# PDO rowCount not returning correct number of affected rows

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having a problem with PDO prepared statement and rowCount returning incorrect number of affected rows.

I have a simple test database of:

```
create table test (
   boolean var1;
);
```

Then I have the following test code:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into test (var1) VALUES (:val)");
$sth->execute(array(':val' => true));
echo $sth->rowCount();
```

Which returns as expected: 1 rows affected

And when I insert an invalid type and the Insert fails:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into test (var1) VALUES (:val)");
$sth->execute(array(':val' => 20));
echo $sth->rowCount();
```

Which returns as expected: 0 rows affected

However, When I have multiple inserts -

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into test (var1) VALUES (:val)");

$sth->execute(array(':val' => true));
echo $sth->rowCount() . ", ";

$sth->execute(array(':val' => 20));
echo $sth->rowCount();
```

**Results in: 1, 1**

And if I flip execution order I get: **0, 1**

Why is the rowCount() -- Affected rows not being set to zero on a fail statement after a success statement?

I'm running php 5.3.6-13 and Postgresql 9.1

Comment: Just turn on exceptions for PDO and get a better way of handling such cases

Comment: This makes sense to me because you re-used the same PDOStatement. If you need a separate rowCount for each statement, then prepare the second statement.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that `$sth->execute(array(':val' => true))` completes successfully thus increasing the `rowCount`, but `$sth->execute(array(':val' => 20))` does not. Here is the state of the `rowCount` for the `$sth` at each stage:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into test (var1) VALUES (:val)");  

# No successful DML queries have been done with the $sth yet.
# rowCount == 0

$sth->execute(array(':val' => true));
echo $sth->rowCount() . ", ";

# rowCount increases because of a successful INSERT statement
# rowCount == 1

$sth->execute(array(':val' => 20));
echo $sth->rowCount();

# rowCount does not increase due to failed INSERT statement
# rowCount == 1
```

Now, lets look at that in the opposite order:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into test (var1) VALUES (:val)");  

# No successful DML queries have been done with the $sth yet.
# rowCount == 0

$sth->execute(array(':val' => 20));
echo $sth->rowCount();

# rowCount does not increase due to failed INSERT statement
# rowCount == 0

$sth->execute(array(':val' => true));
echo $sth->rowCount() . ", ";

# rowCount increases because of a successful INSERT statement
# rowCount == 1
```