# pdo rowCount() provides zero value on successful update of multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am updating multiple records in my mysql DB using the following query.

```
$conn->beginTransaction();
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE products 
                            SET `stock_status`=:stockstatus,
                                `price`=:price  WHERE `id`=:id');
    foreach ($data as $v){
        $stmt->bindParam(':stockstatus', $v['instock'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':price', $v['Price'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $v['ID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }//end foreach
    $conn->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $conn->rollBack(); //roll back changes, if error
    echo 'Update failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
//$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo "$count records updated.";
$stmt->closeCursor(); 
$conn = NULL;
```

rowCount() always produces 0 on multiple row updates. Why is it so ??

From PDO Manual:
rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

But rowCount() is not displaying total number of rows updated in multiple updates ? How can i show the **total number of rows updated** ?

**Update:**

I also tried adding PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS as a mysql connection attribute as follows:

```
    <?php
    $attr  = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS   => TRUE,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    );
    conn = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass,$attr);
    ?>
```

But still multiple row updates are returning **0 records updated**. I have verified that the row indeed updates.

From what i understand "if MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS is on, rowCount() returns the number of **found rows**, **not the number of changed rows**".

So, what is the solution to display total records updated ???

Comment: Where is your while loop terminated??

Comment: Have you verified that the query actually executes successfully?

Comment: @Bad Wolf It is a foreach loop and not while loop. I have verified that the column updates multiple times. Not working for multiple rows.

Comment: Well excuse me. In that case your FOREACH loop is not terminated properly.

Comment: Updated code above..it is terminated properly. that is not the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509336/pdo-rowcount-not-returning-correct-number-of-affected-rows

Comment: Humour me a second and move the echo of the count inside the try{} just after the execute()

Comment: Have you tried both suggested answers combined? It seems to me, that you may get the row-count of `conmmit()` which seems to be always 0 in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you instance your PDO connection object.  You are not going to get an accurate count on an `UPDATE` operation where the keys already exist. `rowCount()` will always return a 0.

You will need to change your line where you create the PDO object `$conn` to include an additional option as [referenced here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#104930) in a comment on the PHP website that states:.

> When updating a Mysql table with identical values nothing's really
>   affected so rowCount will return 0. As Mr. Perl below noted this is
>   not always preferred behaviour and you can change it yourself since
>   PHP 5.3.
>
> Just create your PDO object with  `<?php $p = new PDO($dsn, $u, $p,
>   array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true)); ?>` and `rowCount()` will
>   tell you how many rows your update-query actually found/matched.

It would look something like this based on their example in that comment:

```
<?php
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
?>
```

The option is documented here: http://php.net//manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt->rowCount();` outputs the number of rows of the last execution of the query. Since you are running the query multiple times in a loop and then calling `rowCount()` after the loop it is only returning the number of rows updated by the last run of your query.

If I'm reading your question correctly what you want to do is increment a counter on each iteration of the loop and print the final value at the end.

```
$count = 0;
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE products SET `stock_status`=:stockstatus,`price`=:price  WHERE `id`=:id');
    foreach ($data as $v){
    $stmt->bindParam(':stockstatus', $v['instock'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $v['Price'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $v['ID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count += $stmt->rowCount();
}//end foreach

    echo "$count records updated.";
```